# How are you supposed to display a list of data WITHOUT displaying empty rows?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

`ListViews` don't set their height based on the number of rows they receive. So using a `ListView` is kind of impossible unless you are okay with a bunch of empty rows.

I am not okay with a bunch of empty rows. I cannot imagine any situation in which anyone would be. But that is apparently the only way of displaying a list of data in Xamarin without creating a control yourself, is that right?

How do you display a list in Xamarin?

`HasUnevenRows` doesn't work. I've been using a custom value converter to set the height of the ListView manually but I have to guess at the row height so it's really no good. Honestly, there needs to be a built in control (or an attribute on ListView) that just does this.

Comment: "I cannot imagine any situation in which anyone would be." - this is standard behavior on iOS, and has been for a LONG time.

Comment: I have a list with three things and I only want to see three rows.

Comment: then a Picker or ActionSheet may be a better choice

Comment: A picker wouldn't look right at all or function right at all. ActionSheets appear to only be for iOS.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.displayactionsheet?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: You could set `HaveUnevenRows` to `false` and set `RowHeight` to whatever value applies to your ViewCell (if i'm not wrong default value is 40).

Comment: @FabriBertani that worked. I'm not sure why but it didn't start working until I wrapped the ListView in a Grid.